# Maven project: static resolution error on source branch but not the test branch

Tags: maven

I have created a Maven project, with an src branch and a test branch, on Eclipse.  The following dummy Java class gives a static resolution error on the src branch but compiles fine on the test branch.

```
package mypackage;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;

/**
 *
 */
public class Sandbox {

    /**
     *
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebClient webClient;

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public Sandbox() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

The resolution errors in the src path are as follows:

```
The import com.gargoylesoftware cannot be resolved

WebClient cannot be resolved to a type
```

My POM file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to you under the Apache License, Version
    2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required by
    applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
    CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for
    the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the
    License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.manning.junitbook</groupId>
    <artifactId>ch15-htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ch15-htmlunit</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.36.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.w3c.css</groupId>
            <artifactId>sac</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: is your class located in `src/test/java` folder?

Comment: @Jens I want to understand why it works in src/test/java but not in src/main/java.  Kindly enlighten me.

Comment: Because of the `scope` test. It only will be added to the classpath for test* goals